# First Android Project Errors

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I'v just started building my first Android project with eclipse, according to Lynda's course [Up and Running with PhoneGap](http://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/Up-Running-PhoneGap/99541-2.html).

When i try to run the project (like the demonstration on [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com)), i get the following error message:

> "your project contains error(s), please fix them befor running your application."

```
 Description Resource Path Location Type
 error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value 
              '@string/app_name').  AndroidManifest.xml /android_project    line 49
 Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' 
 with value '@string/app_name').    AndroidManifest.xml /android_project line 52  Android
 AAPT Problem
 The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved   android_project.java  
 /android_project/src/com/example/android   line 23 Java Problem
 DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type  android_project.java    
 /android_project/src/com/example/android   line 25 Java Problem
 The method onCreate(Bundle) of type android_project must override or implement a supertype 
 method android_project.java    /android_project/src/com/example/android    line 28 Java   
 Problem DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type  android_project.java    
 android_project/src/com/example/android    line 30 Java Problem
 Config cannot be resolved  android_project.java    /android_project/src/com/example/android
 line 32    Java Problem
```

Attached the error screenshot

[image: error example]

I can guess what some of the error messages means, but i don't know how to solve them.

Any suggestion?

I'm using windows 8.
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Thanks,
Liron

Answer (score 3):

Check your strings.xml inside your project>res>values and add the string values you are going to use in your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AppName</string>
</resources>
```

Plus, I think you need to **update your .jar file of cordova**.

You can download it from the [phonegap github repo](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/2.2.0).

You can find the lib in the lib/android/ folder.

To create a new project, you can use the lilb/andoird/bin/create.bat file.

Don't forget to clean the project.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'v downloaded [phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/2.2.0), run the create bat file --> opened eclips --> import --> i choose my project and got the error: Application package 'AndroidManifest.xml must have  a minimum of 2 segments', and also checked project>res>values, and it was empty. suggestion's?

Comment: then put a strings.xml file in it. Check updated answer. Put strings in this file.I think you should start developing native apps first to understand basics properly and then move to phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

I think You forgot to set the string values. I haven´t read that tutorial, but there are some strings missin. Check the tutorial, You have to set some strings inside strings.xml in Your res/values folder

### EDIT

go to folder inside Your project "res/values" and open strings.xml. Then begin a new line and put

```
    <string name="example_string">This is an example!</string>
```

The first part "example_string" is the name of the string. This is to refer to this for example inside an xml layout. imagine You have a button in any xml layout:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/example_button"
        android:text="@string/example_string"/>  <-- here you refer to that string inside strings.xml
```

The second part "This is an example" is what will be appear on that button.

But I think it would be better if You learn the basics instead of starting with PhoneGap.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Opiatefuchs, Thanks to the quick response. This tutorial on Lynda is very short. can you please can recommend me another tutorial for building Android project?, or maybe there is a simple explanation for setting string values?